# With pandas how to groupby similar and non-similar partial column values while defining group names

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

So trying to do some analysis on expense data. Have imported a csv and the initial groupby was:

`group_df = df.groupby('Who', as_index=False).sum()`

I've noticed some vendors use slightly different names and want to combine them as part of the overall grouping. The matching text isn't always in the same position in the 'Who' field and in at least one case I've found so far the terms to groupby in 'Who' aren't similar at all ('Rathbone' and 'Yering Station').

```
                                       Who   Amount
0   DE BORTOLI WINES          DIXONS CREEK  -29.54
1   DE BORTOLI WINES  RE      DIXONS CREEK  -20.50
2   DE BORTOLI WINES P/L      DIXONS CREEK  -22.50
3         DE BORTOLI WINES PTY L    BILBUL  -91.00
4     Ezard@Levantine Hill      Coldstream  -31.30
5     Ezard@LevantineHill       Coldstream  -21.10
6  RATHBONE WINE GROUP       PORT MELBOURN  -20.20
7     YERING STATION            YARRA GLEN  -17.05
8    YERING STATION            YARRA GREEN  -31.00
columns: Index(['Who', 'Amount'], dtype='object')
```

Output I want:

```
                                       Who   Amount
0   DE BORTOLI WINES          DIXONS CREEK  -163.54  # all rows containing 'De Bortoli'
1     Ezard@Levantine Hill      Coldstream  -52.40   # all rows containing 'Ezard@'
2  RATHBONE WINE GROUP       PORT MELBOURN  -20.20   # all rows containing 'Rathbone' or 'Yering Station' 
columns: Index(['Who', 'Amount'], dtype='object')
```

I've been going through the pandas doc, website examples and stack exchange and I just can't get to a solution that doesn't throw an error of one sort or another.

I want to be able to specify the group 'Who' if possible (which I think makes this question a bit different from other examples I've seen).

I'm also wondering if it should all be done in one pass or two - i.e. two pass being to do the initial generic grouping on the dataframe and then concatenate the variants on the groupby output.

Am I even approaching this the right way - would it be better to do some consolidation of the dataframe rows before trying to do the grouping?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a dictionary that contains your look-up keys such as `DE BORTOLI` and define the unifying values such as `DE BORTOLI WINES          DIXONS CREEK`. Then you can create a temporary column for this stratifying name, so the information in column `Who` is not lost, and group by this new column:

```
#create dictionary how to translate patterns into categories
#the pattern .* is used as a regex pattern meaning any character before or after this string allowed
transl = {".*DE BORTOLI.*": "DE BORTOLI WINES          DIXONS CREEK", ".*Ezard@.*": "Ezard@Levantine Hill      Coldstream", ".*RATHBONE.*": "RATHBONE AND YERING", ".*YERING.*":"RATHBONE AND YERING"}
#create column with stratified name for grouping
df["strat"] = df["Who"].replace(to_replace = transl, regex = True)
#group and sum
group_df = df.groupby("strat", as_index = False).sum()
print(group_df)
```

Sample output

```
                                    strat  Amount
0  DE BORTOLI WINES          DIXONS CREEK -163.54
1    Ezard@Levantine Hill      Coldstream  -52.40
2                     RATHBONE AND YERING  -68.25
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works though it throws a warning: `"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a Dataframe.` It doesn't seem to effect the outcome but is there a way to reorganise the `df['strat'] = df['Who'].replace...` statement to remove it?

Comment: Fixed the warning message - I had created a new data frame and done some filtering before the `.replace()`. Once I changed the order to do the `.replace()` first then the filter the warning went away... Thanks again!

Comment: Also I slightly modified the regex to cover situations to make it case insensitive by adding `(?i)` to the front of the expression e.g. `"(?i).*EZARD.*": "Ezard@Levantine Hill      Coldstream"`